# How did Dukat contact the founders about joining the Dominion?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, star-trek-dominion

As far as I know Dukat never traveled to the gamma quadrant through the wormhole, so how did he reach them to present his offer for Cardassia to join the Dominion?

Comment: Its been awhile, but isn't it implied that the shapeshifters have spies in the Alpha Quadrant.

Comment: yeah, the founders have already infiltrated many countries before the dominion wars even start. I believe they sent emissaries to countries they felt would side with them from the start, aka the cardassians.

Comment: Yeah but wouldn't the founders still in the Gamma Quadrant have to be consulted as well? I don't doubt their agents had ways to reach them, I'm just not sure what those methods are.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although the two parties are never shown making their deal on-screen, the fourth and final story in [**The Badlands duology**](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/The_Badlands,_Part_IV) does discuss the arrangement with some minor detail.

Apparently, Dukat had initially contacted the Dominion via subspace, thus initiating the talks. After several communications via subspace, [Weyoun 5](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Weyoun) secretly met with Dukat in person to finalize the agreement. The finalization occurred during the time between episode S5E13 "[For the Uniform](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/For_the_Uniform_(episode))" and S5E14 "[In Purgatory's Shadow](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/In_Purgatory%27s_Shadow_(episode))". The signing of the alliance was successful, but ended on a sour note when the [USS Defiant](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/USS_Defiant_(2370)) pursued a Romulan vessel into the section of [The Badlands](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Kamiat_Nebula) where Dukat and Weyoun's ships were hidden.

From dialogue in later episodes, it's apparent that Dukat promised not only Cardassia as an ally, but also the re-capture of [Deep Space Nine](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Terok_Nor) - a major strategic goal of The Dominion. Conversely, The Dominion promised that Dukat would be installed as head of the new Cardassian government and that they would help Cardassia regain its lost territory (including [Bajor](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Bajor)). All of these events/promises were discussed & played out on-screen over the next three seasons.

Comment: It's also worth noting there was that episode where the wormhole kept opening and closing. Off the top of my head, I believe it was because there was a ship there relaying messages, but I am about 95% sure I could be wrong.

Comment: @MyCodeSucks There was a beacon sending coded signals to make it open/close, to trick the Federation into thinking a fleet of cloaked ships were going through the wormhole.  The signals were meaningless, it was just meant to trick them

Comment: Izkata- Doesn't mean the founders didn't get wind of the beacon and take advantage of it.